# colorPrimaryDark doesn't seem to work in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created an app in Android Studio using the Empty Activity template. This template contains a very simple Activity with a layout that just has a TextView.
One of the things it includes is a styles.xml / colors.xml that defines a simple theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

</resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
  <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

According to the Material Theme specification, colorPrimaryDark will change the status bar color on Lollipop devices. I created a Xamarin project with the exact contents of all of these files. The status bar remained black.

What am I doing wrong? This works perfectly fine in Android Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. In the project properties I had the following initially:

```
Compile using Android version: Use Latest Platform (Android 6.0 (Marshmallow))
Minimum Android to target: Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat)
Target Android version: Use Compile using SDK version
```

I changed it to:

```
Compile using Android version: Use Latest Platform (Android 6.0 (Marshmallow))
Minimum Android to target: Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat)
Target Android version: Android 6.0 (API Level 23 - Marshmallow)
```

Target Android version on Compile Using SDK Version needed to be changed to a specific API level.